# How to delete a session after data is saved in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I create a session in my controller like this:

```
Session::put('myoffer', $book->id);
```

In my other controller, I save data to a table and it looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $data = [
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'book_id' => $request->book_id,
        'offer_price' => $request->offer_price,
        'offer_message' => $request->offer_message
    ];
    Book::Create($data);
    return redirect()->route('buyer.dashboard');
}
```

How can I delete the session after the data is saved in the offer table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
session()->forget('myoffer');
```

To delete all session use

```
session()->flush();
```

Your updated code is

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $data = [
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'book_id' => $request->book_id,
        'offer_price' => $request->offer_price,
        'offer_message' => $request->offer_message
    ];
    Book::Create($data);
session()->forget('myoffer');
    return redirect()->route('buyer.dashboard');
}
```

Comment: This solution will not work if you've selected session driver as a database

Comment: Old session entries from the table will be deleted only after Session Garbage Collector is called for database driver. How frequently it should be called, can be controlled by playing around with the 'lottery' variable in sessions.php file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Session::flush();` to delete session
Or to remove an element from the session you use `Session::forget('myoffer');`